# Aggregating LDAP/AD servers

Tags: active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on

Currently, we have a small group of users that are set-up on an Microsoft SBS machine, hence available under active directory.

These users, as well as a bunch of others also have entries on a second LDAP server (openLDAP).  This second server is used for authentication and access control for a few different things such as our internal timesheet web-based system, footy tipping system, forums and subversion repository control.

Thus, for the group that are in the office, they have two separate accounts that they have to remember ID and password for.  Some of these internal systems are not easy to configure to authenticate against multiple LDAP servers (mod_authnz_ldap).

For various reasons, we don't want the extra users and groups cluttering up the Active Directory on the SBS machine.

I would love to be able to somehow set up a virtual LDAP server that could work across the two existing LDAP servers and provide a unified view.  It would pull the user info from AD, and either from the openLDAP server as well, or maintain the additional users and groups internally.

(Actually, internally would probably be better, as there would be groups that would exist only on the aggregated server, to which we would like to assign users from the AD server as members.)

The only think I know of that is close to doing what I want would be the [Penrose virtual directory server](http://docs.safehaus.org/display/PENROSE/Home), but I wanted to see if there were other options out there before I investigated that much further.

Comment: What did you end up implementing to solve this problem?  We're looking at some sort of virtual directory solution and I'm curious what your experience has been.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above you can use a [virtual directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_directory) product to give an interface to a centralized LDAP service.

Some companies that have virtual directory products:

- MaXware
- Radiant Logic
- OctetString
- Persistent enQuire
- iPlanet Directory Access Router
- Oracle
- Sun
- Many others

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is usually called a Virtual Directory, or perhaps an LDAP proxy.

Once you start getting more complex than just two simple systems you want to start thinking about an Identity Management solution, perhaps a Meta directory system.

Virtual directories are nice if that is sufficient, but often it is more expedient to actually collect all the data into one meta directory and expose parts of that as needed.

Lots of products in both spaces, usually cost, as you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all sure, but you may be able to do something with [ADAM](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/adam/default.mspx) and [proxy authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.12.proxy.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could at least use the same user-IDs for AD and OpenLDAP. This would solve double user-id problem.

In addition you could automatically sync password from AD to OpenLDAP or other way around. This would solve problem of users having to remember multiple passwords.

Comment: I don't think you can pull the password information out of AD - which makes syncing difficult...